# How to pass via url a PHP variable to be inserted in a JS script url

Tags: javascript, php, variables, url

I need to pass a couple of PHP variables via url. These variables need to be inserted in a JS script which loads a script.

I have this code on the HTML (.php) page which loads the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.example.com/index.php?controller=GzFront&action=load&cid=1&layout=calendar&show_header=F&eid=6262&group=1&local=4"></script>
```

I need to pass the variables "eid" (number) and "group" (number) via URL from another page.

How can I do this? Should I use a url like `www.domain.com/scriptpage.php?eid=6262&group=1` ? And then, how can I put these 2 variables in the script url?

I'd like to use one script/one page to show different contents depending on the variables passed via URL from a HTML (.php) page.

Comment: `how can I put these 2 variables in the script url`...using `echo`. e.g. `src="https://www.example.com/index.php?...eid=<?php echo $_GET["eid"]; ?>&` ...etc. Make sense?

Comment: You can just print the variables in the URL using echo. Please try to learn some PHP basics because you'll be posting a lot of basic questions on this site. There are lots of short video tutorials to learn the basic stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Solved this way:

Add the variable to the url using ?:

```
pagename.php?var1=par1&var2=par2
```

In the script url add:

```
<?php echo $_GET['var1']; ?>
<?php echo $_GET['var2']; ?>
```

Where you need the variable.

```
https://www.example.com/index.php?eid=<?php echo $_GET["eid"]; ?>&group=<?php echo $_GET["group"]; ?>
```

that's it!

Comment: Glad you solved it. Just an aside: You know you don't need to put `<?php ... ?>` on every individual line of PHP? That will get very cluttered. You can just open with `<?php`, write as many PHP lines as you like, and then close with `?>` (or if it's the end of the file and there's no HTML or static content after that, you don't even need to bother with the closing bracket.)

Comment: never use code like this 

<?php echo $_GET['var1']; ?>